# Replace paragraph in text

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How can I use a shell command (sed or awk) to replace a paragraph in a file like the following:

```
bala bala ba1
balabala.
leave me here.

this paragraph
yes, I'm going
to be replaced

The rest contains
should not be replaced.
```

After replacing:

```
bala bala ba1
balaba.
leave me here.

New contains,
I'm replacement!

The rest contains
should not be replaced.
```

I declare the original contained in a variable `$OLD`, and new is contained in another variable `$NEW`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have variables containing your new and old paragraphs, as in

```
$ echo "$old"
this paragraph
yes, I'm going
to be replaced
```

and

```
$ echo "$new"
New contains,
I'm replacement!
```

You can read the file (assuming it's called `infile`) into a Bash variable and use parameter expansion:

```
$ contents=$(< infile)
$ echo "${contents/$old/$new}"
bala bala ba1
balabala.
leave me here.

New contains,
I'm replacement!

The rest contains
should not be replaced.
```

To change the file in-place:

```
echo "${contents/$old/$new}" > infile.tmp && mv infile.tmp infile
```